# How to update csv values given their row and column numbers are known with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some code that looks through the lines of a .csv file and checks if the lines contain any values from a specific column of another .csv file.

These **files** look like this:

Lookup file:

```
0:  TextExclude, text, other
1:  aa,        , x ,   y
2:  bb,        , x ,   y
3:  cc,        , x ,   y
```

File where I'm looking to find these values in:

```
0: x, longtext, exclude
1: x, helloaa,  0
2: x, testaa,   0
3: x, testcc,   0
4: x, no,       0
5: x, aabb,     0
```

The output of my code is supposed to change the value of the 'contains' column from 0 to 1 in every row except for row 4, yielding this **expected output** csv table:

```
0: x, longtext, exclude
1: x, helloaa,  1
2: x, testaa,   1
3: x, testcc,   1
4: x, no,       0
5: x, aabb,     1
```

Since my code can output the **row numbers** where a match is found and the **column number** is already defined, I was wondering what would be the best way to solve this and update the .csv file accordingly?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas
findlist = []
linecount=0
       
with open('lookup.csv', 'r') as f:
    column_names = ["TextExclude", "Exclusion", "Filename"]
    r = pandas.read_csv(f, names=column_names)
    findlist = r.TextExclude.to_list()

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()
    for line in f: 
        linecount = linecount +1
        if any(listelement in line for listelement in findlist):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should parse datafile.csv using pandas, not just read it as a flat text file. That way you can isolate your search to the correct column and also update the third column more easily.

```
import pandas
findlist = []
linecount=0

with open('lookup.csv', 'r') as f:
    column_names = ["TextExclude", "Exclusion", "Filename"]
    r = pandas.read_csv(f, names=column_names)
    findlist = r.TextExclude.to_list()

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as f:
    df = pandas.read_csv(f)
    for ri, row in df.iterrows():
        if any(x in row[1] for x in findlist):
            row[2] = "1"

# print result to stdout
print(df)

# or write result to a file:
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

If you are wondering what version of Pandas and Python you are using, you can run these two commands:

Python version:
`python --version`

Pandas version:
`python -c "import pandas;print(pandas.__version__)"`

Here is a second way of searching that breaks the steps out a little more which might aid in debugging:

```
import pandas
findlist = []
linecount=0

with open('lookup.csv', 'r') as f:
    column_names = ["TextExclude", "Exclusion", "Filename"]
    r = pandas.read_csv(f, names=column_names)
    findlist = r.TextExclude.to_list()

def search(search_in):
    for to_find in findlist:
        if to_find in search_in:
            return True
    return False

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as f:
    df = pandas.read_csv(f)
    for ri, row in df.iterrows():
        if search(row[1]):
            row[2] = "1"

# print result to stdout
print(df)

# or write result to a file:
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've copied this code but receive a TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable for line 13. Since im quite new to python I can't find the reason for this problem.

Comment: Did you copy and paste my program into a new python file and run it in isolation without any of your other code? This program runs for me. I am using Python v3.9.1 and Pandas v1.3.5.

Comment: @Anthony I posted a second style of searching which might be easier to debug, since it does the searching in more separate lines of code, which could let you isolate the problem due to a more specific line number.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated! I've cleared the error, however now I'm trying to figure out, why my exclude column remains 0 for all rows.